# Nest.js use custom value in the request object

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I create a guard that are like these

```js
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class CompanyGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const token = request.headers['token'];
    if (token) {
      const company = await this.authService.validateToken(token);
      return company ? true : false;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to keep the value of company on the request object, so I can use it later on my controller. How to do that in Nest.js? I tried to look it on the docs, but I'm confused. Should I use the [session](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/session) or there are more simple way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just add the `company` to a custom field on the request. `request.company = company` and then in the controller you can use `@Req()` to get the request object and `.company` to get the company value. Or you could create a [custom decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators) to get the company for you.

Comment: How would these receive the proper typing?

Comment: You make an interface `export interface CustomRequest extends Request{ company: CompanyType; }` that you can use instead of the standard

Comment: But then you have to type cast that everywhere the request object is used? Or can you add it globally?

Comment: Are you not already using `Request`? A refactor command should be able to take care of that. Yes you could use some [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to take care of it, but that doesn't always play well with tests. I much rather use a custom interface to be explicit about where things come from.